# Loading a XAML file related to a control programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to have a custom WPF control whose content is defined in XAML but avoiding the use of a `UserControl`. This is because a UserControl makes it impossible to add `x:Name` to its content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751325/how-to-create-a-wpf-usercontrol-with-named-content/3413382

My files are laid out like this:

```
.
│   App.config
│   App.xaml
│   App.xaml.cs
│   MainWindow.xaml
│   MainWindow.xaml.cs
│   WpfScratch.csproj
│
├───bin
│   ├───Debug
│   │   │   WpfScratch.exe
│   │   │   WpfScratch.exe.config
│   │   │   WpfScratch.pdb
│   │   │
│   │   └───Controls
│   └───Release
├───Controls
.       MyPanel.cs
.       MyPanel.xaml
```

and the source of the relevant ones is:

#### `MyPanel.cs`

```
public class MyPanel : Control
{
    static MyPanel()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyPanel)));
    }

    public MyPanel()
    {
        var templateUri = new Uri("/WpfScratch;component/Controls/MyPanel.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        Template = (ControlTemplate) Application.LoadComponent(templateUri);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Body", typeof(object), typeof(MyPanel), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object Body
    {
        get => GetValue(BodyProperty);
        set => SetValue(BodyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", typeof(object), typeof(MyPanel), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object Footer
    {
        get => GetValue(FooterProperty);
        set => SetValue(FooterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

#### `MyPanel.xaml`

```
<ControlTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfScratch.Controls" 
                 TargetType="local:MyPanel" >
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" x:Name="Content">
        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="Aqua"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Footer"
                              Content="{Binding Footer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              Margin="0, 10" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="Magenta">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Body" 
                              Content="{Binding Body, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

#### `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfScratch.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfScratch"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfScratch.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <controls:MyPanel x:Name="HelloWorldPanel">
        <controls:MyPanel.Body>
            <Label x:Name="HelloLabel">Hello!</Label>
        </controls:MyPanel.Body>
        <controls:MyPanel.Footer>
            <Label x:Name="WorldLabel">World!</Label>
        </controls:MyPanel.Footer>
    </controls:MyPanel>
</Window>
```

---

My main concern is the loading of the XAML file, i.e.:

```
 var templateUri = new Uri("/WpfScratch;component/Controls/MyPanel.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
 Template = (ControlTemplate) Application.LoadComponent(templateUri);
```

1. Is `Application.Load()` the way to go? UWP seems to deprecate it in favour of `XAMLReader.Load()`, but I'm not sure how I would get the correct stream for that. I tried digging into the sources of Application.LoadComponent and there's some logic involved with processing pack URIs
2. The URI is a hardcoded mouthful and seems not very resilient to refactoring. Is there a terse way of saying "hey my XAML file is right next to this one"?

Comment: I can't see where the name is being used. Am I overlooking something? Is it used in code which you haven't included in the question?

Comment: @Peter - which name?

Comment: Any of them. You say that the reason for avoiding UserControl is that it prevents you using names, but I can't see why any of the names in the code is actually necessary. All of the binding seems to be to properties rather than elements.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - code clarity and being able to navigate the visual tree easier when debugging

Comment: And yes, obviously it would be useful if I needed to identify the control in codebehind, but that’s not my use case yet and I was motivated by the previous reasons to look into this, since it’s a vexing restriction with a confusing error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conventional way of attaching default template to custom control is to specify default style inside a special resource dictionary. For this approach to work three conditions should be met:

1) Resource dictionary should be located at `Themes/Generic.xaml`. There you should place a default style for your custom control (that in turn should set `Template` property to default value).

2) Your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file should contain `ThemeInfoAttribute`.

3) Your custom control should override default style key inside a static constructor, using `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata` method.

Alternatively, if you are not planning on reusing your custom control, you can just drop the default style into `App.xaml` resources and avoid above shenanigans.

For more info see: https://michaelscodingspot.com/2016/12/24/explicit-implicit-and-default-styles-in-wpf/

Comment: Will this work is this control is in a subproject that’s referenced by the main app’s project in a solution? That is, is the theme tied to the assembly rather than the app itself?

Comment: @millimoose, the three points are for using it as a subproject. The line beginning "*Alternatively*" is the simpler approach which suffices if you just want to tie the theme to the app.

Comment: @millimoose, yes, first approach will work "out of the box": you will be able to use your custom controls the same way you use default ones - just by referencing them in your xaml. Second  approach will technically work as well, but you would have to manually specify path to resource dictionary inside `App.xaml` every time you create a new application that depends on your sub-project. For that reason I wouldn't recommend using it across different assemblies.